# Django forms is_valid is working without parenthesis

Tags: python, django

At line 6 of my code I forgot to add the parenthesis to is_valid() but my code works fine without the parenthesis. Why is this? I'm still able to access form.cleaned_data. After filling out a form, the info is saved to my database and the terminal displays the print functions. SignUp() is a ModelForm.

## views.py

```
def signup(request):
    form = SignUp()
    context = {'form': form}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUp(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            note = "Thanks {} for joining!".format(form.cleaned_data['firstname'])
            print("Name: {}".format(form.cleaned_data['firstname']))
            print("Age: {}".format(form.cleaned_data['age']))
            return render(request, 'one_app/sign_up.html', {'form': form, 'note': note})

    return render(request, 'one_app/sign_up.html', context)
```

## models.py

```
class Members(models.Model):

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.SmallIntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
    employeed = models.BooleanField()
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}"
```

## forms.py

```
class SignUp(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Members
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'firstname': 'First Name:',
            'lastname': 'Last Name:'
        }
```

Comment: This can't "work fine", because `form.is_valid` is a function, and therefore truthy - so this will always try to save (and likely throw an error) even if the form is not valid. Try deliberately filling out the form incorrectly and submitting it and you should see.

Comment: it's not throwing an error. The information is saved to my database.

Comment: and the print functions display the cleaned_data in the terminal.

Comment: Can you share the relevant form and model classes and describe how you are filling it in incorrectly? It's possible that the data is still possible to be saved to the database even though it's not something you would want to allow the user to do. (Eg a registration form with a weak password.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I don't see any validation on your form at all, so it seems that `if form.is_valid()` would always pass, just as your current `if form.is_valid` would. But that doesn't make the latter correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every ModelForm also has a `save()` method. This method creates and
> saves a database object from the data bound to the form.

**The reason why you're able to access `form.cleaned_data`**

> Note that if the form hasn’t been validated, calling `save()` will do so
> by checking `form.errors`. A `ValueError` will be raised if the data in
> the form doesn’t validate – i.e., if `form.errors` evaluates to `True`.

If you try and omit the statement `form.save()` inside your `if` statement your code will raise errors.

> The form’s data will be validated the first time either you call
> is_valid() or access errors.

---

You were able to access `form.cleaned_data` because when `form.save()` was called it **internally** checked for `form.errors` in order to make sure a correct instance of your Model gets created.
Now as stated in the documentation `form.cleaned_data` is available either when you call `form.is_valid()` or access `form.errors` in this case form errors were accessed during `form.save()` call. 
Hopefully, now you understood why you were able to access `form.cleaned_data`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: Good point! Once the if clause passed, the save method was successfully called. Very well!

Comment: Are you saying calling save() creates the cleaned_data attribute? It's my understanding that the cleaned_data attribute isn't created until is_valid() is called.

Comment: I understand why the code runs form.save() but I don't understand why the values were saved under the cleaned_data attribute if I didn't call is_valid(). Is the data saved to form.cleaned_data after calling save() or is_valid()?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `form.is_valid` returns a method.

Anything is different from None.

It will always pass.

Try this:

```
if None:
    print('Empty')

if not None:
    print('Not Empty')
```

You will notice that 'Not Empty' will be printed.

Comment: this does not explain why `form.cleaned_data` is accessible.

Comment: @VishalSingh Sure thing. It doesn't. Take a look at the question: " I forgot to add the parenthesis to is_valid() but my code works fine without the parenthesis. Why is this?". This one was answered.

Comment: I was talking about form.cleaned_data returned the values and the data was saved in the model.

Comment: Nevermind. I just realized you answered my question. Thanks for the clarification. So just to clarify, calling save() is when the data is assigned to the cleaned_data attribute regardless of whether or not is_valid() was called?